# Error writing mnemonic recovery seed to file: LibraWalletGeneric: Permission denied (os error 13)

Tags: diem

While trying to save my Diem (Libra) wallet mnemonic recovery seed to disk I get the following message;

> [ERROR] Error writing mnemonic recovery seed to file: LibraWalletGeneric: Permission denied (os error 13)

However when starting the client with sudo I have no issue;

```
sudo ./scripts/cli/start_cli_testnet.sh
a w /home/user/wallet/wallet.wallet
>> Saving Libra wallet mnemonic recovery seed to disk
Saved mnemonic seed to disk
```

What should I do as a standard to solve this issue? The most obvious workaround being to run the client as root or to modify the write folders permission.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution was simply to save the wallet to the current folder, i.e;

```
libra% a w ./wallet.wallet
```